# How to merge several PDF files?

Tags: pdf, merge

There are a lot of software in Windows to merge PDF files but how can we do the same in Ubuntu?

Comment: I found [this link](https://blog.dbrgn.ch/2013/8/14/merge-multiple-pdfs/)

Answer (score 311, accepted):

PDF Arranger formerly known as PDF-Shuffler.

If you want a tool with a simple GUI, try *pdfarranger*. It allows for merging of PDFs as well as rearranging and deleting pages. For batch processing and/or more complicated tasks, pdftk is of course more powerful.

[image: Screenshot of PDF-Shuffler]

To install PDF Arranger in Ubuntu 20.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install pdfarranger
```

Comment: I tried this - it didn't work on 10.04

Comment: On 12.04, pdfshuffler always complains that there are "too many values to unpack", making it unusable.

Comment: For me it works under 12.04 64-bit, pdfshuffler version 0.6.0

Comment: Installs and works like a charm on 14.04. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: I used to use pdftk for this behavior.  Thanks for the PDF Shuffle reference.  It looks really slick.

Comment: I can also confirm `pdfshuffler` works fine on 14.04 amd64.

Comment: This is the quickest and easiest solution. Thank you! (Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit)

Comment: This works well in many cases but I noticed that it stripped out hyperlinks. Using pdftk does not strip out hyperlinks. So, if there is any complexity to the PDFs that you are concatenating, I would use the command line tool; at the very least, thoroughly test your output file.

Comment: just tried for one case but I got an error "multiple definitions in dictionary" so it could not create an output. their issue tracking on that is open for quite some time without resolution so I assume the project is not very active, would not recommend!

Comment: Also works great on 16.04.1

Comment: Gave it a try and works well on 17.04. Very easy to use for basic merge.

Comment: This doesn't work for combining encrypted transcripts.

Comment: Tried PdfShuffler 0.6.0 (`apt-get install pdfshuffler`) on Ubuntu 14.0 64-bit and it works with one caveat - It has problem dealing with some special characters in the filename (in my case pdfshuffler cannot load filename with `#`)

Comment: Version 0.6.0 works like a charm on 18.04

Comment: Works greatly on 18.04

Comment: Just used it on 19.10, to merge and crop a series of pdf, worked like a charm.

Comment: This tool has been renamed to `pdfarranger` as of Ubuntu 20.04. You can still install `pdfshuffler` via apt, but it is just an empty pointer to `pdfarranger` which is also the command you'll need after install.

Comment: This is crashing in ubuntu 16.04. I have tried pdftk which is not gui based application

Comment: @CarlZulauf can you provide a link to documentation showing this renaming of pdfarranger? I'm not seeing any evidence of this in apt and not able to get pdfshuffler to work at that.

Comment: @topher217 APT will tell you pdfshuffler is just pdfarranger. On Ubuntu 20.04 try `$ apt show pdfshuffler` and look closely.

Comment: @CarlZulauf maybe you or I have a manually added an apt repo to pdfshuffler? I'm not seeing anything. Here is the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/0iKY4nJN) of the output from `apt show pdfshuffler`. This is after running `sudo apt update` just in case. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 with `apt -v` returning `apt 1.6.14 (amd64)`. The only docs on pdfarranger I found were the [github repo](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger) which doesn't appear to give any apt based instructions for installation but rather via pip.

Comment: Works well in Ubuntu 22.04 as well!

Answer (score 583):

## `pdftk`

To merge two pdf files, `file1.pdf` and `file2.pdf`:

```
pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf cat output mergedfile.pdf
```

More info available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20131207083425/http://ubuntuhowtos.com/howtos/merge_pdf_files)<sup>Way Back Machine</sup>.

To install, run:

```
sudo snap install pdftk
```

Comment: pdftk is buggy - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdftk/+bug/779908.

gs might be slow, but does the work perfectly [IgnitE's answer]

Comment: @PushpakDagade ghostscript messes up with annotations, particularly comments that have been checked (check box ticked with checkmark), will no longer have this checkmark. I am not aware of a way around this. Also, if you merge PDF v1.5 + 1.6, output will be 1.4 by default. That is strange behavior.

Comment: This is beautiful. Working pretty fine on 14.04.5 LTS and we can merge PDF's with different page size/orientation. Produces high quality and low size files. Thank you!

Comment: pdftk has an unusual usage where commands `cat` and `output` follow variadic input arguments and followed again by an output argument.

Comment: The package seems to have been removed in 2018.04.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I just downloaded it as a snap install.

Comment: @Max do you know what is the difference between the two snaps at https://snapcraft.io/search?category=&q=pdftk ?

Comment: FYI: `sudo snap install pdftk` - there is no release candidate for the aptitude app anymore, it was deprecated by the author, who created the snap package.

Comment: @GrayedFox [in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165823/925128)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul [in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165823/925128)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul On the website, `pdftk-smoser` is marked as obsolete.

Comment: A handy shortcut: pdftk file* cat output mergedfile.pdf

Comment: Nice tool. Works like a charm on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: It works great. To install on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS do: `sudo apt install pdftk-java`

Comment: `jdk` is an overkill and should not be necessary.

Comment: I have the following error: Error: Failed to open PDF file: ...

Comment: `cat` is not needed I think.

Comment: `sudo snap install pdftk` can be used in Ubuntu 20.04 and pdftk is accepting "*.pdf" as a valid parameter.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028522/how-can-i-install-pdftk-in-ubuntu-18-04-and-later it exists as `pdftk-java` and can be used as `pdftk`

Comment: `pdftk` does not work if there spaces in the filenames

Comment: Snap is not necessary anymore : `sudo apt install pdftk`

Answer (score 271):

*Ghostscript* is a package (available by default in Ubuntu) that enables you to view or print PostScript and PDF files to other formats, or to convert those files to other formats.
To use Ghostscript to combine PDF files, type something like the following:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sOutputFile=finished.pdf  file1.pdf file2.pdf
```

Here is a brief explanation of the command:

```
gs         starts the Ghostscript program.
-dBATCH    once Ghostscript processes the PDF files, it should exit.
           If you don't include this option, Ghostscript will just keep running.
-dNOPAUSE  forces Ghostscript to process each page without pausing for user interaction.
-q         stops Ghostscript from displaying messages while it works
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite 
           tells Ghostscript to use its built-in PDF writer to process the files.
-sOutputFile=finished.pdf
           tells Ghostscript to save the combined PDF file with the specified name.
-dAutoRotatePages=/None
           Acrobat Distiller parameter AutoRotatePages controls the automatic orientation selection algorithm: For instance: -dAutoRotatePages=/None or /All or /PageByPage.
```

Your input files don't even need to be PDF files. You can also use PostScript or EPS files, or any mixture of the three.

There is a lot you can do with Ghostscript. You can read its [documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current) for more details.

<sub>[Source](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8229-putting-together-pdf-files)</sub>

Comment: True, but it's *incredibly* slow. I just tried concatenating 45 x 400K, single-page PDFs. `pdftk` took 0m0.484s, `gs` took 1m32.898s (that's almost 200x slower) The file from `gs` was about 21% smaller though.

Comment: this command also works if you use a wildcard for the list of files to be combined. for example, replace `file1.pdf file2.pdf` with `file*.pdf`

Comment: For me `gs` worked with some "non conformant" PDFs where `pdftk` would just run forever.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my need!

Comment: Use `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` option from quality improvement. All thanks due to the original [contributor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19358402/205230)

Comment: @AntoniosHadjigeorgalis Just for reference and good understanding: that's not the command supporting wildcards, that's actually the shell replacing `file*.pdf` with `file1.pdf file2.pdf` before passing the arguments to the command.

Comment: I merged ~20 small pdfs into a single file in a fraction of a femto-second with `gs`. No need to download 70MB of `pdftk`. Thanks @ignite!

Comment: +1 Worked with encrypted pdfs as well (these annoying files that can be viewed but not merged without a password).

Comment: This worked fine for me on Ubuntu 16.04 with no extra downloads. Merging 4 pages was almost instantaneous.

Comment: @aidan sounds like gs rerenders the files instead of just copying the content.  This might be a good thing if you want a distiller like workflow

Comment: The `gs` method will break the href and url link in the pdf created by pdflatex. pdfshuffler can keep the link.

Comment: I'm using this to concatenate 3 files, and `gs` inexplicably takes the title of one of them and uses it as the title of the new document (shown in the title bar by the PDF viewer). I wonder if the new title could be specified explicitly.

Comment: This works:`gs -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -sOutputFile=finished.pdf  file1.pdf file2.pdf`, no need for the `-q` and `-dnopause` which did not help to output more silent. No need for `dAutoRotatePages`.

Comment: Worked really well, I used `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sOutputFile=finished.pdf *` (with the wildcard). Great, and open source. Thanks!

Answer (score 163):

You also also use pdfunite to merge pdf documents :

```
pdfunite in-1.pdf in-2.pdf in-n.pdf out.pdf
```

To install `pdfunite` if it is not installed already, run:

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
```

Comment: WARNING: An existing file `out.pdf` will be overwritten without warning, so `pdfunite *.pdf` won't work as expected.

Comment: @krlmlr You can always put the output into another directory.

Comment: Fair enough, `cp` also overwrites last argument without warning. This is just for rushing users (like myself) -- I was lucky I had a backup of the file in question...

Comment: Upvote: This is a simple command-line tool without a click-and-drool GUI like many of the other answers here. It nicely encapsulates the complexities of the (largely equivalent) GhostScript solution.

Comment: This is also very fast. Does the job well. On a very slow server (aws t1.micro), gs takes 9 secs, pdftk takes 4 secs and this pdfunite takes 0.9 secs for merging two files!

Comment: This is also available under Cygwin.

Comment: To get this on Ubuntu 16.04, run `sudo apt-get install poppler-utils`. You'll then be able to type `pdfunite --help` and see that it's installed.

Comment: Interesting: `pdfunite` is available by default in Ubuntu MATE 20.04. (I certainly didn't install it...)

Comment: The sheets were returned with different sizes.

Answer (score 38):

[PDF Chain](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pdfchain) [image: Install PDF Chain]

A very nice solution is PDFChain. It's GUI is a frontend of PDFTK where you can merge, split or even add some background to your PDF files.

Comment: This is the best answer. It works perfectly, regardless of the Ubuntu version.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 14.04 without hassle!

Comment: Works great on Ubuntu 18.04!

Comment: [so goo that it was removed from ubuntu software in 18.04(!?)](https://snapcraft.io/search?category=&q=pdfchain)

Comment: @user2413 that's a snap store, not the only source for software in Ubuntu. Trying to search in `apt` didn't give any results either though :/

Comment: How is this installed in newer Ubuntu versions?

Answer (score 19):

An alternative approach is to use Latex as explained in this post (**without root access** assuming that you have **pdflatex** installed):
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8662/merge-two-pdf-files-output-by-latex

This is useful in case you do not have the mentioned tools nor root privileges, but you do have pdflatex.

I copy the tex code below to merge `file1.pdf` and `file2.pdf`. Create a file called `output.tex` and put:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{file1}
\includepdf[pages=-]{file2}
\end{document}
```

And to compile, simply use: `pdflatex output.tex`

The merged file will be named as `output.pdf`.

Comment: This is the best approach because the result will always be there, no bugs

Comment: This breaks hyperlinks.

Answer (score 13):

Give PDFMod a try, it’s from the GNOME project:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/PdfMod

```
sudo apt install pdfmod
```

Comment: does not do merging.

Comment: it did merging in the past, now it's just crashing, I used the pdfshuffler instead and it worked great

Answer (score 11):

Use pdfsam http://www.pdfsam.org/ it's very good for splitting and merging pdfs

```
sudo apt install pdfsam
```

Comment: Used it under 19.10 to merge file: simple interface, a few options, works very well. But other features such as crop are premium options. ```sudo apt-get install pdfshuffler``` did the trick :-)

Answer (score 10):

I use pdfseparate to extract specific pages from big pdf file:

```
pdfseparate -f  156 -l 157 input.pdf  output_%d.pdf 
pdfseparate -f  1   -l 2   input.pdf  output_%d.pdf
```

and aftewards I join them all via command:

```
pdfunite $(ls -v output_*.pdf | tr '\n' ' ') out$(date  +%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S ).pdf
```

This joins:

```
output_1.pdf output_2.pdf output_156.pdf output_157.pdf
```

into:

```
out2014-12-14_23_25_36.pdf
```

May be there is an easier way how to cope... :-)

#### Installation instructions:

```
sudo apt install poppler-utils
```

Comment: The process substitution is superfluous and [potentially even harmful](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  A correct an much simpler command line is `pdfunite output_*.pdf out$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S).pdf` but it lacks the ordering of `ls -v`.  An obvious and trivial fix is to name your files so that they naturally sort in the order you want to include them. If you absolutely want `ls -v`, you can at least lose the pipe to `tr`, which accomplishes nothing here.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [jPDFTweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/), [pdfsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/?page_id=32) or [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic/firth/software/pdfjam).

(That said, I use pdftk.)

Comment: It would be better if these were separate answers so that they could be upvoted separately and edited separately.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [pdftk](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pdftk) to merge and modify PDF documents in general. Alternatively there's an online service to do just that: http://www.pdfmerge.com/

Comment: pdftk is mentioned in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/2802/2355

Answer (score 2):

You can see use the free and open source [pdftools](https://github.com/raffaem/pdftools) (disclaimer: I am the author of it).

It is basically a Python interface to the Latex `pdfpages` package.

To merge pdf files one by one, you can run:

```
pdftools --input-file file1.pdf --input-file file2.pdf --output output.pdf
```

To merge together all the pdf files in a directory, you can run:

```
pdftools --input-dir ./dir_with_pdfs --output output.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

- I wanted it to be easily accessible so I created a right-click shortcut in Nautilus (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto)
- I wanted it to be very quick so I used pdfunite
- pdfunite only accepts the filepaths in the middle of the command so I had to scratch my head to manage the spaces in the filepaths. So I took the assumption that all filepaths will start with "/home/" and end with ".pdf"

Here is the result:

```
#!/bin/sh
CLEANED_FILE_PATHS=$(echo $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS | sed 's,.pdf /home/,.pdf\\n/home/,g')
echo $CLEANED_FILE_PATHS | bash -c 'IFS=$'"'"'\n'"'"' read -d "" -ra x;pdfunite "${x[@]}" merged.pdf'
```

Juste paste this script in

> /home/your_username/.local/share/nautilus/scripts

and name it "merge_pdfs.sh" (for example). Then make it executable (right-click on merge_pdfs.sh -> Permissions tab -> tick "Allow executing file as a program"

So now to merge pdf files, you just have to select them -> right click -> scripts -> merge_pdfs.sh and it will create a "merged.pdf" file in the same directory

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find `pdfarranger` in `snap` (Ubuntu 22.04).

Thus I installed `sudo snap install pdfmerger`.

This tool also has a simplistic GUI and worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

**qpdf**

This also worked for me:

```
sudo apt install qpdf
qpdf --empty --pages in1.pdf in2.pdf in3.pdf -- out.pdf
```

For some encryption related reason which I don't fully understand `pdftk in1.pdf in2.pdf in3.pdf cat output out.pdf`, pdftk was failing with:

```
Error: Invalid PDF: unknown.encryption.type.r
```

on certain PDFs I downloaded, even though they didn't require a password to open.

Related threads:

- https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk/-/issues/87
- [How to remove the password from a PDF?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828720/how-to-remove-the-password-from-a-pdf)

Source code: https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf

License: Apache.

Project description:

> QPDF is a command-line tool and C++ library that performs content-preserving transformations on PDF files. It supports linearization encryption, and numerous other features. It can also be used for splitting and merging files, creating PDF files (but you have to supply all the content yourself), and inspecting files for study or analysis. QPDF does not render PDFs or perform text extraction, and it does not contain higher-level interfaces for working with page contents. It is a low-level tool for working with the structure of PDF files and can be a valuable tool for anyone who wants to do programmatic or command-line-based manipulation of PDF files.

Tested on Ubuntu 23.10, pdftk 3.3.3, qpdf 11.5.0.