# What is a quick way to connect two or more pdfs together using the command-line?

Tags: command-line, pdf

I have a few pdf files (e.g., `small1.pdf`, `small2.pdf`, `small3.pdf`) that I'd like to be able to join together to form one larger pdf (e.g., `large.pdf`).

- What is a good option for doing this on the command-line?

Comment: [Couturier](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/icombiner-for-pc-linux/) is a GUI way I know of doing this, but AFAIK it is no longer maintained since 9.04, and I don't know of an equivalent terminal command myself.

Comment: Sorry, I just realised I've probably created an almost duplicate question. I just saw the following answer in the "related question" area suggesting the use of `pdftk` in the above case: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2799/how-to-merge-several-pdf-files/2802#2802

Comment: I would suggest closing this question then, unless that doesn't work out for you. At any rate, glad to know you've found a possible solution.

Comment: @Warrioring64 With regards to closing, I don't mind either way. The other question asked about merging pdfs in general (including the use of GUIs) whereas this question is specifically focused on command-line options. Perhaps this question will reveal some other useful answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used pdftk for that:

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

then:

```
pdftk small1.pdf small2.pdf small3.pdf cat output large.pdf
```

Comment: +1 If you are planning on working with PDFs on the command line pdftk should be in your toolbox.

Answer (score 5):

PDFJam and PDFtk can do this too, but since you probably have Ghostscript installed already (all one line):
`gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=large.pdf -f small1.pdf small2.pdf small3.pdf`