# How can we automatically merge PDF files?

Tags: pdf

when using FreePDF if I process multiple files it asks me to "Add to next pdf?" which appends them at the end of the last PDF name.

I want it to do this automatically without user intervention... is there any application for this? This is being used via a batch routine so want something that I can encorperate into this routine???

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2799/how-to-merge-several-pdf-files ;) (see the command line option).