# How to remove the password from a PDF?

Tags: command-line, gui, pdf

I have a password protected PDF file. I know the password but in order to share the file, I have to remove the password from the PDF and share an unprotected copy. How can I do this in Ubuntu with or without the GUI?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

**The easiest way GUI** (recommended for novice)

Open the protected file and use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> or use print option to print the file, now save the file as pdf.

---

**Using Command line**

If you have pdftk already installed you can skip step1

Step 0: To check if Pdftk is already installed

```
sudo apt list | grep pdftk
```

If output contains '[installed]' tag with pdftk then you can skip step1
i.e if the output is like this

```
pdftk/xenial 2.02-4 amd64 [installed]
```

Step 1: Install pdftk

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

Step 2: Run following command

```
pdftk /path/to/input.pdf input_pw <yourpassword> output out.pdf
```

---

If you don't want to install pdftk there is another utility qpdf which is automatically installed (at least on 16.04 which I am using)

To use qpdf for generating unsecured pdf run following command.

```
qpdf -password=<your-password> -decrypt /path/to/secured.pdf out.pdf
```

For detailed information take a look at [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/197195/how-to-remove-a-password-from-a-pdf-file-in-linux/) HTG tutorial

Comment: Unfortunately, `pdftk` failed to open my PDF: `Error: Invalid PDF: unknown.encryption.type.r`. (Meanwhile, Evince is able to open it perfectly fine.) qpdf did the trick for me.

Comment: pdftk issue: https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk/-/issues/87

Comment: In MacOS Monterey PDFTK has the same issues. But `qpdf` solves the issue. `brew install qpdf`.

Comment: The GUI qpdfview will not print to file (pdf). pdftk must be used.

Answer (score 78):

I tried this in ubuntu mate 19.04:

```
sudo apt-get install qpdf
qpdf --password=YOURPASSWORD-HERE --decrypt input.pdf output.pdf
```

[Source](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/)

EDITED: You can also open the file in chrome first and then save as PDF.

Comment: Awesome! pdftk didn't work for me due to encryption (`InvalidPdfException: unknown.encrpytion.type.r`), but qpdf did!

Comment: I used this script to unencrypt all the pdfs in the current directory `mkdir dec; ls *.pdf | xargs -i qpdf --password= --decrypt {} dec/{}`

Comment: A safer version to do all files in a directory.. `for i in *.pdf; do qpdf --password="$mypass" --decrypt "$i" "${i%.pdf}.decrypted.pdf"; done`

Comment: Actually `qpdf --decrypt in.pdf out.pdf` (no password) worked fine for me 

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question, but seems to be a reference on the matter and, surprisingly, none of the answers tells us how to avoid passing the password on the command line (which may be a source of leakage). Of course, since this is about removing the password protection from the file, maybe you don't care. But maybe you received a pdf from a company which used some data of yours to encrypt the file, and you'd like to avoid leaking it.

With `pdftk` we can use:

```
pdftk protected.pdf input_pw output out.pdf do_ask
```

The password is then queried in the terminal and you can type it.

With `qpdf` it is a little less direct. `qpdf` can read a password from `stdin` passing `-` to the `--password-file=` option:

```
qpdf --password-file=- --decrypt protected.pdf out.pdf
```

Once you enter that, `qpdf` will be waiting for input from stdin. You can then type `<yourpassword>`, <kbd>RET</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> sends `EOF` in Linux. In Windows, I think it would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, but I'm not sure).

If you have an older version of `qpdf` (prior to v10.2.0), `--password-file=` didn't work this way, but one could still read a whole argument from `stdin` with the `@-` option. That given, you can use:

```
qpdf @- --decrypt protected.pdf out.pdf
```

Then type `--password=<yourpassword>`, <kbd>RET</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

Comment: If you put a space in front of your command it *should* avoid adding it to the history.

Comment: add "echo YOUR_PASSWORD" at the begining and you can skip the interactive method "echo YOUR_PASSWORD | qpdf @- --decrypt protected.pdf out.pdf"

Comment: @DiegoAndrésDíazEspinoza I would not recommend that, as it would defeat the purpose of this answer altogether. If you are concerned at all in hiding your password, that is. Doing that is not much different than using the `--password=` option directly.

Comment: @thoroc I don't know about the space at the start and the history. But, as far as I know, the command you give the terminal should still be visible in the list of processes, etc. Again, if you are concerned in hiding your password, I still wouldn't do that.

Comment: @thoroc ignoring commands starting with a space needs to be configured in HISTIGNORE Bash variable. It may or may not be the default on various systems.

Comment: @user1079505 good point, I don't recall having to set that in the last 15 years though. :)

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
pdftk input.pdf output output.pdf user_pw YOURPASSWORD-HERE
```

This takes your `input.pdf`, removes the passwords and exports it as `output.pdf`.

You may want to take a look [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/) to explore additional mehods.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: Didn't work for me either. This works by putting the user_pw param just after input.pdf (it seems params are positional). So "pdftk input.pdf user_pw YOURPASSWORD-HERE output output.pdf " should work (I've used input_pw instead of user_pw).

Comment: Latest versions seem to require the above format and parameter order

Answer (score 5):

Use this zsh function:

```
pdf-unencrypt () {
    : "Usage: <file>
Uses ghostscript to rewrite the file without encryption."
    local in="$1"
    gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="${in:r}_unencrypted.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite -f "$in"
}
```

`:` is a `no-operations` function. `$in:r` gets the variable without its extension. You obviously need `ghostscript` installed.

Comment: In more recent versions of ghostscript, you'll need to remove the `-c .setpdfwrite -f` from the above command line. Otherwise, version 9.54 or later will fail with `Error: /undefined in .setpdfwrite`. (I don't know why there's a forward-slash in that.) And version 9.53.x will give you a warning message stating `The .setpdfwrite operator has been deprecated and will be removed entirely in the next release of Ghostscript`

Comment: I've seen this command many times yet when I run it I get an error `This file requires a password for access`. So at least in recent versions of `gs` it doesn't seem to be working or at least not for me.

Comment: _almost_ works, except instead of being prompted for a password when I try to save an edit, it just freezes (on `Preview.app`)

Comment: edit: oh wait, if I then used `Preview.app` to Export it (as PDF) again, I can now successfully save edits. Score.

Answer (score 3):

if you don't have the password you can still unprotect the pdf document thanks to ghostscript :

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=unencrypted.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f my-protected-pdf-file.pdf
```

if you need to install GhostScript :
[How to install newer version of ghostscript on server than provided from ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076846/how-to-install-newer-version-of-ghostscript-on-server-than-provided-from-ubuntu)

Comment: Are you sure you do not need a password?  If this works, password protection of PDF is equivalent to no protection.

Comment: give it a try, you will tell

Comment: I tried and got a message `This file requires a password for access. Error: /invalidfileaccess in pdf_process_Encrypt`.

Comment: i think you are right, this removes the protection when the file is locked for edition, not for reading

Comment: does not work on readable pdfs with password: `Error: /undefined in .setpdfwrite`

Answer (score 2):

Rising the topic from the dead a little bit here (but I am a new Linux user, so...);

1. Anyhow, I also used the file for which I had known the password. But I used "Master PDF Editor 5" (unregistered, free version) to remove the password (File - Properties - Security - No Encription).
2. However, since "Master PDF Editor 5" leaves the watermark (which I personally, do not mind), I re-opened (the now unlocked file) in Libre Office Draw and removed the watermark.
3. I exported the file in PDF, which additionally resulted in tremendous compression without any losses. It was a very simple file; one sheet only, with text in the table, but the above process reduced the size from 70-ish KB to 22-ish KB.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a password, you can use the following to remove the password

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFPassword=password -sOutputFile=output2.pdf -f input.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I might as well chime in with a little script I built around pdftk and [gum](https://github.com/charmbracelet/gum).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "$1" || ! -f  "$1" ]]; then
  echo "Select a file:"
  file="$(gum file)"
  echo -e "${file}\n"
else
  file="$1"
fi

pdftk "${file}" input_pw output "${file//.pdf/_decrypted.pdf}" do_ask
```

You can provide a file as the first parameter and the decrypted file will be saved with `_decrypted.pdf` postfix. If you don't provide a file name as the first parameter it will bring up gum's file chooser.