# How do I remove password from a PDF using ghostscript, when password is known?

Tags: password, encryption, pdf, ghostscript

I have an encrypted pdf, and I am aware of the password, and I would like to use the Ghostscript to make them unencrypted, so they don't require any password to be opened.

I tried using the following, But it seems I'm doing something wrong

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=OUTPUT.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f -sUserPassword=mypassword encrypted.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a pdf that is encrypted and you know the password you can decrypt the pdf as follows

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFPassword=password -sOutputFile=output2.pdf -f input.pdf
```

Now let me tell you about each option being used

1. `-sDEVICE`: its a device, use `man gs` to learn more
2. `-dNOPAUSE`:  Disables  the  prompt and pause at the end of each page.  This may be desirable for applications where another program is driving Ghostscript.
3. `-q`: do things quietly, no logs on screen
4. `-sPDFPassword`: Its the password
5. `-dBATCH`: I think it is for quitting the `gs`

Like every Linux Program, the Documentation (man pages) is written very poorly and doesn't have a lot of information.

Comment: This method works well, but it does so by "printing" the PDF to a new PDF.  So you lose any fancy things like forms or interactivity.  Sometimes this is what you want though.  The other `qpdf` answer leaves these interactive elements in place if you prefer to keep them.

Answer (score 3):

If using a different tool like `pdftk`/`qpdf` first is an option, the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828720/how-to-remove-the-password-from-a-pdf) have a couple of methods, for example
`qpdf -password=mypassword -decrypt encrypted.pdf OUTPUT.pdf`

Comment: qpdf didn't bloat the output pdf like gs