# Remove Adobe protection from PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, ghostscript, pdftk

When I open a PDF it prompts for a username and password.  If I open it with any other program than Adobe it says only Adobe can open this PDF.  I am not a fan of being limited to Adobe and we have already paid for this PDF (I have the password).  I need to remove the password so it can be accessed by my teammates. The print button is disabled in Adobe Reader.

"The document you are trying to load is protected by security features and
requires Adobe Reader."

I have viewed many similar questions but nothing works.
[How to remove the password from a PDF?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828720/how-to-remove-the-password-from-a-pdf)
[How do I remove password from a PDF using ghostscript, when password is known?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443188/how-do-i-remove-password-from-a-pdf-using-ghostscript-when-password-is-known)

I have tried all of the below and all have failed:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=OUTPUT3.pdf -c 3000000 setvmthreshold -f -sUserPassword=password pp_en_protected_password.pdf  

gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=OUTPUT3.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f -sUserPassword=password pp_en_protected_password.pdf  

qpdf -password=password --decrypt pp_en_protected_password.pdf out.pdf  

pdftk pp_en_protected_password.pdf output pp_output1.pdf user_pw password
```

WSL - Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/q/179064/1240908 help?

Comment: Which distro and version of linux are you using?

Comment: @DanielT No, that doesn't help.  I had already viewed that as well, but that requires the print button to work.

Comment: What happens if you install Okular, uncheck "Obey DRM limitations", open the PDF, then try to click past the "only Adobe can open this PDF" warning?

Comment: @DanielT Thanks!  Okular helped me see that the file I want is actually an embedded file.  When I save the embedded file and try to open it in Okular it only prompts for a password (and not a uname) so it fails.