# Create PDF with 100 pages, only 6 of them in color

Tags: printing, pdf, colors

I'm trying to upload a book to bookmundo with most of it black text on white paper, just a few pages with color images in between.

Being "clever" I used Libreoffice, exported the book as PDF and uploaded this PDF to bookmundo. They digest the PDF and produce their Preview, which looks perfect, but is considered 106 colored pages, so the price climbs from 13 Eur to 25 Eur, which is not an option.

They also accept docx, but trying that they insert blank pages and don't recognize some of my page breaks. However, when I upload docx, they correctly see only 6 colored pages and the price is correct.

Any idea, how I can produce correcty colored / black-whited PDFs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what they technically need, it's hard to answer this definitively, but I assume there is some page-level colouration hint that they're looking at that Acrobat Pro can handle selectively (can it?)

So my first suggestion is to **Ask them what they need**. This is always worthwhile when dealing with printers. They may even handle it for you, especially for a longer print run.

But you might be able to export one version in black and white, one in colour and then *combine* select pages into a mixed document. This assumes the underlying library respects the page-level hints. There are [several tools](https://askubuntu.com/q/2799/449) you can try for this: `pdfchain` or `pdfshuffler` for GUI options and `pdftk` or `pdfunite` for command line or scripted options. Try a couple of these and see.

But yeah, failing all that, ask Bookmundo to fix it for you.