# Old timer attempting to make the big switch

Tags: scanner, image-processing

```
OS: Mint 18.3 sylvia
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.14.9
Uptime: 5h 38m
Packages: 2392
Shell: bash 4.3.48
Resolution: 1280x1024
DE: XFCE
WM: Xfwm4
Theme: Mint-Y-Dark
GTK Theme: Mint-Y [GTK2]
Icon Theme: Mint-X-Dark
Font: Noto Sans 9
AMD Athlon 7750 Dual-Core @ 2.707GHz
GPU: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS780 (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.14.9,LLVM 4.0.0)
RAM: 706MiB / 3660MiB
```

Help.

I have been thus far a life long Windows user but I have now become so fed up with the environment such as windows 10 interface and the ridiculous amount of personal data they mine and I am looking to switch to Linux to protect my privacy and be inherently more secure.
I have been using Microsoft Office 2010 Pro and have cross graded my PC as above from Microsoft Windows. Most of the compatibility issues have been resolved but I do have one residual issue that relates to scanning.

I need to be able to load a multi paged PDF file into scanning software. When loaded into the scanning software I need the thumbnails for all pages to appear as a list in the left hand part of the screen with the first or last document appearing full size on the rest of the screen.

Crucially, I then need to be able to append new scanned documents to the file so that the new thumbnails appear at the bottom of the thumbnail list with the new scanned documents appearing full size on the screen.

I then need to be able to save the image complete with the recently appended page(s) with the original file name appearing as default so that I can then just click save to save the whole document with the newly appended page(s).

For some reason the seems to be very difficult to do.

Originally my files that were ported from Windows were TIFF format but I converted these to PDF as I thought it may help but it did not.

I have tried gscan2pdf, GIMP and xsane imaging but neither product has such an append function.

Can anyone suggest any other products which will be able to do this?

Thanks

Exasperated from UK

Comment: I don't think I understood completely, are you looking for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2799/how-to-merge-several-pdf-files)?

Comment: That question is almost tl;dr . Linux is not a drop in replacement for windows and you may need to flex on this one issue. inparticular the thumbnails. The rest you should be able to do

Comment: Yes i am trying to look for alternative solutions and adjust my workflow, i will have a look at pdf shuffler pomsky

Answer (score 2):

PDF Arranger (*pdfarranger*) is an application which allows one to merge or split pdf documents (*Export* -> *Export All Pages to Individual Files*) and rotate, crop and rearrange their pages using an interactive and intuitive graphical interface. To install PDF Arranger in Ubuntu 20.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install pdfarranger
```

All the pages being edited in are arranged on the same canvas. You can edit PDF files in PDF Arranger by selecting a page or a file and dragging it to a new position, including dragging it in or out of the canvas.

In Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier PDF Arranger had not yet replaced the older PDF Shuffler application. To install PDF Shuffler in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install pdfshuffler
```